Solve $\left|\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & a & a+x & a+x^2\\ a & 1 & a+x^2 & a+x\\ a+x & a+x^2 & 1 & a\\ a+x^2 & a+x & a & 1\\ \end{smallmatrix}\right|=0$
I have a problem that ask me about solving the equation $\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a & a+x & a+x^2\\
a & 1 & a+x^2 & a+x\\
a+x & a+x^2 & 1 & a\\
a+x^2 & a+x & a & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}=0$, where a is a complex number. I am working on it with some results about block matrices, however, it is taking me a long time and big polynomials while this problem is done to be resolved faster. Any ideas on it?

Please do not use formulas that are too tall (especially not four lines tall) in subject lines. They mess up how lists of questions are displayed.

Your 4x4 matrix is quite nice in that the top-left 2x2 block matches the bottom-right, and the bottom-left matches the top-right.  This lets you use the last determinant identity from  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Determinant which simplifies the work down to solving two 2x2 determinants.

As DotCounter pointed out just use the formulae $$\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\ B& A\end{pmatrix} = \det(A - B) \det(A + B).$$

@DotCounter I was using this identity but does it hold when A is a singular matrix? By the way, do you have a proof of this result?

Hint For square matrices $A, B$ we have the special identity (linked by DotCounter in the comments)
$$\det\pmatrix{A&B\\B&A} = \det(A - B) \det(A + B) .$$
In our case our $A$ and $B$ themselves have the special form
$$A := \pmatrix{\alpha &  \beta \\  \beta & \alpha} , \qquad
  B := \pmatrix{\gamma & \delta \\ \delta & \gamma},$$
hence so does
$$A \pm B
= \pmatrix{\alpha \pm \gamma &  \beta \pm \delta \\
            \beta \pm \delta & \alpha \pm \gamma},$$
so the determinants $\det(A \pm B)$ are themselves differences of perfect squares:
\begin{align}
\det(A \pm B)
= (\alpha \pm \gamma)^2 - (\beta \pm \delta)^2
= [(\alpha \pm \gamma) + (\beta \pm \delta)] [(\alpha \pm \gamma) - (\beta \pm \delta)],
\end{align}
hence
$$\det \pmatrix{A&B\\B&A} = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta) (\alpha + \beta - \gamma - \delta) (\alpha - \beta + \gamma - \delta) (\alpha - \beta - \gamma + \delta) .$$

 In our case, $\alpha = 1, \beta = a, \gamma = a + x, \delta = a + x^2$, and substituting (and combining factors of $-1$) recovers the factorization in Dietrich Burde's answer: $$(x^2 + x + 3 a + 1)(x^2 + x + a - 1)(x^2 - x + a - 1)(x^2 - x - a + 1) .$$ Now it's just a matter of separately setting each quadratic factor to $0$ and solving for $x$.


This is the way I took but this identity holds even when A is singular?

Yes. But even if you weren't sure whether the identity held when, e.g., $\det A=0$
(a situation like which is disallowed for some block matrix determinant formulas) you could notice that $\det \pmatrix{A&B\B&A}$ and the result are both polynomials, in particular continuous, so since the formula holds on the dense set of $a$ where $\det A \neq 0$, it holds everywhere.

I see, thanks for the help

The determinant factorises nicely as
$$
(3a + x^2 + x + 1)(a + x^2 + x - 1)(a + x^2 - x - 1)(a - x^2 + x - 1)=0,
$$
see the determinant identity mentioned above.
